# Unidirectional OneToMany JPA persist

Tags: java, jpa

I have some bizarre behavior with a unidirectional OneToMany relationship in JPA.
This is my model:

```html
Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID_PK")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long oid;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID_FK", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID_PK")
    private List<Attribute> attributes;

  
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID_FK", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID_PK")
    private List<Price> prices;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTES")
public class Attribute implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID_PK")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int oid;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRICES")
public class Price implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PRICE_ID_PK")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int oid;

    private int value;
}
```

I create a "Product" and persist a product in the db.

Later I want to add some attributes.

This is the code that does it:

```html
  //start transaction
  for (SomeElement el: someElements) {
        Attribute attr = new Attribute(el);
        product.getAttributes().addAttribute(attr);
   }

   for (SomeOtherElement el: someOtherElements) {
         Price price = new Price(el);
         product.getPrices().addPrice(price);
   }
   product = em.merge(product);
   em.flush();
   ...
   //end transaction
```

The code does not report any errors, but only the first element of each collection is added. Is this the correct behavior?
What would be the suggested way to add a whole collection of elements?

Thanks in advance
VR

Comment: Hi, I have tried persisting a product entity using entities as modeled by u. It works fine.  What is this SomeElement ? Is it an entity  or just a sudo code ?

Comment: It is just pseudo-code. Basically it is list of DTOs that I turn into objects for storing in the database. In any case, I made my associations bi-directional and store each attribute/price separately and it works now. However, I am still baffled by the behaviour as I am obviously doing something wrong but I do not know what

Comment: what i generally do is to have a many to one mapping as source and use mapped by in one to many part which will we be on the inverses side of the relation. Do u want to see an example of that ?

Comment: Thanks, but I already did it this way. I was hoping to have a uni-directional association because it better represents what I want